# JQuery set field value with variable label name

Tags: jquery, variables, label, field

I tried to use variable in label[name=] tag.
I used variable cause im in a each loop.

See my code, thats what i tried.

So my code is

```
var value = 'ads';
var cookies = 'test';

console.log(value);
console.log(cookies);

$('label[name='+value+']').val(cookies);
```

So i see in my console.
ads
test

But it didn't replace the value of my html field.

```
<input type="hidden" name="ads" value="" class="hidden">
```

Value stays empty.
When i tried it like here it works.

```
$('input[name=ads]').val(cookies);
```

No error shown.

Comment: you are not closing the square bracket in `$('input[name=ads').val(cookies);` it should be `$('input[name=ads]').val(cookies);`

Comment: Thx, i just update my code. But it don't help me with my questions :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Update**

If you use `val()` is value of content be changed but if you want to change attribute you need to use `attr()`

```js
var value = 'ads';
var cookies = 'test';

console.log(value);
console.log(cookies);

$('input[name='+value+']').attr("value",cookies);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" name="ads" value="" class="hidden">
```